# orderByChild() on an array

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase for Android and found that the `orderByChild("key")` method does not seem to work on an array; I'm trying to retrieve all `award_year`entries, ordered by their `year` value.

This is what I've came up with:

```
mDatabase.child("awards").orderByChild("createdAt").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         final AwardType awardType = new AwardType();
         final ArrayList<Award> awards = dataSnapshot.getValue(awardType);
      }
});
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

I've added the rules:

[image]

My structure like this:

```
{ "awards": [
    {
        "award_body": "2009 QR Master Design Awards",
        "award_received": "Finalist for Bathrooms $30,000, Qualified Remodeler Magazine",
        "createdAt": "2015-11-20T03:43:58.009Z",
        "logo": {
            "__type": "File",
            "name": "tfss-b2a0130d-d9ac-46e6-a29f-c9d9db666909-qualirem1.png",
            "url": "awards/thumbnails/tfss-b2a0130d-d9ac-46e6-a29f-c9d9db666909-qualirem1.png"
        },
        "objectId": "0cE0zA7ciS",
        "updatedAt": "2015-11-20T03:46:57.472Z",
        "year": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "award_years",
            "objectId": "Zp3oDtzpTY"
        }
    },
    {
        "award_body": "2014 NAHB",
        "award_received": "Best of American Living Awards (BALA) Platinum Award Winner, Kitchen Remodel $100,001 \u0026 over",
        "createdAt": "2015-11-20T05:36:55.359Z",
        "logo": {
            "__type": "File",
            "name": "tfss-3cce2507-18fe-4aac-b039-54c343f27473-nahb.png",
            "url": "awards/thumbnails/tfss-3cce2507-18fe-4aac-b039-54c343f27473-nahb.png"
        },
        "objectId": "1ckh7kjxfN",
        "updatedAt": "2015-11-20T05:45:02.307Z",
        "year": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "award_years",
            "objectId": "aL7crUC7Qc"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the code that uses `orderByChild()` and does something with the resulting snapshot(s), it's impossible to say anything. Also: you've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That is actual data; I added the query I used to fetch.

Comment: Include the code of how you handle the data. Recent questions show that the most likely mistake is in there. Without seeing a minimal *complete* reproduction, we're just guessing. Also note that I asked for the data as text, not as an image.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen There you go, I've edited by question.

Comment: The JSON you shared has no nodes name `awards` or `award`, which are what you use in your code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Good morning! I've updated my code, again.